# CSS match height of other elements in row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, and I'm trying to make a row of boxes be the same height.

Here is a dumbed-down example:

CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
    border:1px solid black; 
    height:100%;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">Less text</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a fringilla magna, nec vestibulum felis. Donec sollicitudin porta sem eu dignissim. Vivamus pellentesque leo vel pellentesque blandit</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a fringilla magna, nec vestibulum felis. Donec sollicitudin porta sem eu dignissim. Vivamus pellentesque leo vel pellentesque blandit
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a fringilla magna, nec vestibulum felis. Donec sollicitudin porta sem eu dignissim. Vivamus pellentesque leo vel pellentesque blandit
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a fringilla magna, nec vestibulum felis. Donec sollicitudin porta sem eu dignissim. Vivamus pellentesque leo vel pellentesque blandit
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in the first box in the row being small, and the third box being very large. I want them all to have the same height.

How do I make the height of all the boxes in the row match the tallest box without setting a static height? I don't know how big the largets box will be. I know I could do this with a table, but that would not be optimal. Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Here is a [bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/hOENpl5Gi8). I did some googling but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484089/equal-height-columns-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: Bootstrap will never help if you want to play with `height`s ... Only `width` it caters !! This can be possible using JQuery / Javascript !!

Comment: @hopkins-matt thanks, that looks like it will help

Comment: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) shows several approaches; in particular, using `display: table` is well-supported by browsers and fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS Only solution**

Note: Use carefully and target the styles to your ***specific*** `.col-md-4` elements. But for your code sample:

```
.col-md-4 {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    border:1px solid black; 
    height:100%;
}
```

**Demo** http://www.bootply.com/JXL6MYXiWO

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! I was struggling to get any of the other solutions working, this one worked like a charm. I was only using `.col-md-4` for this example, I have my own class in the real code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var highestCol = Math.max($('.div01').outerHeight(),
                              $('.div02').outerHeight(),
                              $('.div03').outerHeight());
    $('.col-md-4').outerHeight(highestCol);
})
```

jQuery example, quite fast and effective.
Just give those divs additional unique classes, e.g. `div01`, `div02`, `div03`.
Check out http://jsfiddle.net/a7jow8c3/

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is probably your best option at this point in time. See this article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And current browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox