# Boostrap equal height + background color issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need the left and right column to be equal height.
On the website the left side (image) is always heigher, which is not clear in the fiddle.

Also, the title has no background. Only the content marked in red has a background color. But I'm not ably to give dat one a height that makes it up to the bottom of the right div.

`Link to fiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/MaartenTe/a3d5ugar/

[image]

Comment: Why don't doing this only with css ?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your problem?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484089/equal-height-columns-in-bootstrap-3)?

Comment: Added an image in first post.
The equal height is not really the issue, its more the inner div's height that is my problem.

The red should be upto the bottom of the grey part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to "play" with $(document).ready()

not on load

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6e6w1sq

```
$(".red-c ").height(maxHeight-$(".lesgever_top").height());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t6e6w1sq/1/

Comment: It seems refreshing does sometimes break this. Any idea?

Comment: put calculations in funcion and trgger it on DOM ready and resize event
window.onresize = function(event) {...});

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.eq {
    background-color:blue;
}
.red-c {
    background-color:red;
    min-height:500px;
}
```

and for you title just add that span in the para div

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it should solve your problem :)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content_height= $("img").height()-$(".lesgever_top").height();
  $(".red-c").css("height", content_height);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/pb9zzxpc/2/embedded/result/)