# Make HTML columns stay same size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML page with 2 columns next to each other. Every time i have less text in the one column's height becomes smaller.

I want the column's height to stay the same no matter what content there is in the columns. Please note I will have more than 2 columns. When I add more columns the columns will go underneath.

This is what I have so far:

HTML

```
           <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-post services-single-post">
                    <div class="single-post-title">
                        <h2> Music Production </h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-post-image">
                        <img src="img/music.jpg" alt="Post Title">
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-post-info">
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-post-content">
                        <p>We also offer music production. We have been making music for over 10 years using industry standard software and equipment. If you are looking for the best you've come to the right place.  </p>
                    <a href="services-post.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="services-post services-single-post">
                    <div class="single-post-title">
                        <h2>Graphic design</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-post-image">
                        <img src="img/s4.jpg" alt="Post Title">
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-post-info">
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-post-content">
                        <p>
                            Graphic design solutions</p>
                    <a href="services-post.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.services-post {
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;

}
.services-post img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.services-post .post-info {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.services-post .post-comments-count {
  text-align: center;
}

.post-info .post-comments-count i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.post-info .post-comments-count a {
  color: #FFF;
}
.post-info .post-date .date {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.post-title h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #828282;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.post-title h3 a {
  color: #535b60;
}
.post-summary {
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
.post-summary p {
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: justify;
}
.post-more {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
/* Single Post */
.services-single-post {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
.single-post-title h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #828282;  
}
.single-post-info {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #828282;
}
.single-post-info i {
  color: #333;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.single-post-image {
  text-align: center;
}
.single-post-image img {
border:none;
}
.single-post-content {
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #CCC;
}
.single-post-content p {
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [equal height columns in bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484089/equal-height-columns-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with bootstrap 4 out of the box because it integrates flexbox, but you can make it work with bootstrap 3, too.

I added a class called `.equal-height` to the row that will have columns that you want equal-width, and added `.equal-height { display: flex; }` then added `height: 100%` to `.services-post` so that the border will extend to the bottom of the column.

```css
.services-post {
  background: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  height: 100%;
}
.services-post img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.services-post .post-info {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.services-post .post-comments-count {
  text-align: center;
}

.post-info .post-comments-count i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.post-info .post-comments-count a {
  color: #FFF;
}
.post-info .post-date .date {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.post-title h3 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #828282;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.post-title h3 a {
  color: #535b60;
}
.post-summary {
  margin: 10px 20px;
}
.post-summary p {
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: justify;
}
.post-more {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
/* Single Post */
.services-single-post {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
.single-post-title h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #828282;  
}
.single-post-info {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #828282;
}
.single-post-info i {
  color: #333;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.single-post-image {
  text-align: center;
}
.single-post-image img {
border:none;
}
.single-post-content {
  margin: 30px 0 20px 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #CCC;
}
.single-post-content p {
  color: #828282;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: justify;
}
.equal-height {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row equal-height">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="services-post services-single-post">
        <div class="single-post-title">
          <h2> Music Production </h2>
        </div>

        <div class="single-post-image">
          <img src="img/music.jpg" alt="Post Title">
        </div>

        <div class="single-post-info">
        </div>

        <div class="single-post-content">
          <p>We also offer music production. We have been making music for over 10 years using industry standard software and equipment. If you are looking for the best you've come to the right place. </p>
          <a href="services-post.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="services-post services-single-post">
        <div class="single-post-title">
          <h2>Graphic design</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="single-post-image">
          <img src="img/s4.jpg" alt="Post Title">
        </div>

        <div class="single-post-info">
        </div>

        <div class="single-post-content">
          <p>
            Graphic design solutions</p>
          <a href="services-post.html" class="btn">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi there, your answer works perfectly but it does not position the columns nicely in IE. Please may you assist me with that

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your extra markup but this looks like Bootstrap. The grid system columns need to be nested inside of an element whose class is labeled with "row":

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6"> content</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> more content</div>
</div>
```

Does your HTML have this?

Comment: Yes i have that

Answer (score 0):

You can make the table row's *minimum height* static by entering the exact pixel amount you need it to be. Try adding the following to the `css` and implementing the relevant class in your `html`.

```
.tableHeight{
    min-height: 20px;
}
```